# How to save content in postgres, so it wont become 1 div?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js, pgadmin

I want to create a news website and currently I stuck on how to save data, so it wont become 1 big div (e.g. I want to have several paragraphs or photos on 1 news page). I am using react, pg and sequelize

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to structure the data you are about to save, and then make a "parser" that parses the structured data into different elements on the news page. Have a look at JSON.